# I keep getting a "missing type specifier" error C4430

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am sorry in advance if I do a terrible job of explaining what my problem is.  I am also sorry about the length of this post.  This is my first time trying to ask a question on this site and I'm a bit nervous about asking questions in general.  I am working on a program to make a stack data structure using a linked list for the college Data Structures class I am taking and have encountered an error in my program which is causing my entire program not to work.  We used a couple of files from a program we did recently to create the project.  If it helps anything I am using Visual Studio 2019.  Any help would be appreciated and I thank any of you who took the time to read through all of this.

Here is my first header file: "SingleLinkedList Head.h"

```
#include <string>
typedef string Item;     //This is the line which causes the problem.  It keeps saying that there is a
                         //missing type specifier, yet the type is clearly specified as "string"?
class StringNode {
private:
    Item item;          //The error above is causing some of the things in my program which
    StringNode* next;   //use "Item" as the datatype to also give me a C4430 Error

    friend class StringLinkedList;
};

class StringLinkedList {
public:
    StringLinkedList();
    ~StringLinkedList();
    bool vacant() const;     //Checks if the list is empty
    const Item& topDeck() const;          //Displays the front item of the list (C4430 Error)
    void drawCard(const Item& item);      //Adds an item to the front of the list (C4430 Error)
    void discard();     //Removes an item from the front of the list
    void showHand();    //Prints the entire list
private:
    StringNode* head;
};
```

Here is my first implementation file: "SingleLinkedList Imp.cpp"

```
#include "SingleLinkedList Head.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

StringLinkedList::StringLinkedList()
    :head(NULL) {}

StringLinkedList::~StringLinkedList() {
    while (!vacant()) discard();
}

void StringLinkedList::discard() {
    StringNode* excess = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete excess;
}

bool StringLinkedList::vacant() const { return head == NULL; }

const Item& StringLinkedList::topDeck() const { return head->item; }    //C4430 Error

void StringLinkedList::drawCard(const Item& i) {        //C4430 Error
    StringNode* draw = new StringNode;
    draw->item = i;
    draw->next = head;
    head = draw;
}

void StringLinkedList::showHand() {
    StringNode* card = head;

    while (card != nullptr) {
        cout << card->item;
        card = card->next;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Here is my second header file: "LinkedStack Head.h"

```
#include "SingleLinkedList Head.h"

class LinkedStack
{
public:
    LinkedStack();
    int size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    const Item& top();     //Displays the top of the stack
    void stack(const Item& item);     //Adds an item to the top of the stack
    void unStack();     //Removes an item from the top of the stack
private:
    StringLinkedList S;
    int n;
};
```

Here is my second implementation file: "LinkedStack Imp.cpp"

```
#include "LinkedStack Head.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

LinkedStack::LinkedStack()
    : S(), n(0) {}

int LinkedStack::size() const { return n; }

bool LinkedStack::empty() const { return n == 0; }

const Item& LinkedStack::top() { return S.topDeck(); }

void LinkedStack::stack(const Item& i) {
    ++n;
    S.drawCard(i);
}

void LinkedStack::unStack() {
    if (empty())
        cout << "The stack is empty.";
    else
    {
        --n;
        S.discard();
    }
}
```

Here is my main file: "LinkedStack Main.cpp"

```
#include "LinkedStack Head.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedStack B;

    B.stack("Bob");

    if (!B.empty())
        cout << B.top() << endl;
    else
        cout << "The stack is empty.";

    B.stack("Devin");
    B.stack("Claire");
    B.stack("Malachi");
    B.stack("Diana");

    B.unStack();
    B.unStack();
    B.unStack();


    return 0;
}
```

I don't exactly know what is causing this to happen.  I am also getting some strange errors telling me to put semicolons in strange places (one asked my to put a semicolon before "item" in the typedef line, which doesn't make much sense).  My best guess is that somewhere in my program I have overlooked a mistake of mine and the program just needs to be looked over with a fresh pair of eyes.

Note: I am aware that using "using namespace std;" is kind of a cardinal sin when it comes to programming.  I used it in my code because it was used in the examples we did in class.  I will shift away from using it in programs which aren't based on such examples (i.e. programs that are entirely my creation).

Comment: Try `typedef std::string Item;` You'd be best to always specify the namespace and avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Your compiler is just being unhelpful. Clang reports this differently: "`error: unknown type name 'string'; did you mean 'std::string'?`"

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work then.  However, I found that I had more errors in some other places and after fixing those and adding the "std::" it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help!  It is still amazing what a fresh pair of eyes can do for a problem.  Again, thank y'all!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `std` namespace in "SingleLinkedList Head.h". Use `typedef std::string Item;`. You keep getting "missing type specifier" because "string" isn't defined yet(so it is not a type spcifier), the compiler "thinks" that you are writing `typedef <sometype> string` but `<sometype>` is missed.

Note: `using namespace std;` is another possible legal fix that will be accepted by compilers but it is strongly not recommended in header files.

Comment: Please don't recommend `using namespace std;` in a header.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am not recommending it but just a possible fixing for examples. But you are considerate and I will edit it.

Comment: You can, after all, just have `using std::string;`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the answer to take the dangerous recommendation out (and upvoted).